# Play music on Asterisk without blocking extension

Tags: asterisk, lua

I'm writing an Asterisk dialplan using Lua.

First, I'm reading a sequence of numbers then I send a HTTP Post to a webservice. I would like to play some music to the user while the script performs the request.

There are 3 functions to play sound files (MusicOnHold, Background and Playback) but they all block the execution of the script until music finished.

Is there a workaround? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks (I'm also open to normal dialplan answers since it is easy to translate it to Lua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. There is another command that starts the Music on Hold without blocking execution: [`StartMusicOnHold`](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-APP-B-313.html)

I spent 4 hours finding this function so I hope this helps someone else. There is also `StopMusicOnHold` but for most things it isn't needed since when you use another command like `Dial` it gets automatically stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to play an audio track while waiting for the response of an API that can be a little slow.

To add to the update to the accepted answer, update your `musiconhold.conf` with your required user defined context and with the correct directory and then call it with `StartMusicOnHold(default)`.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1198670)